# Methods to prevent triggering more than one event-functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two events, one that triggers on `touchstart` and one that triggers on the custom event `longTouch`.

```
    events: {
        "touchstart .o_slide": "startDragEventHandler",
        "longTouch .overview .o_slide": "slidePreview"
    },
```

Basically, I need to make sure, that only one of the events fires at a time, to make sure, that when the users makes a longTouch to preview a slide (the `slidePreview` function), then the `startDragEventHandler` can't also be firing.

Problem is, that if the user longTouches to create e preview, but moves the finger just a little bit, then the drag functions will also initiate, messing up the UX.

Can I write code in one of the functions, that makes sure they other function will return before executing the body? Which different methods applies to this problem?

Comment: I would update the startDragEventHandler so that it calculates the dragged distances. If the dragged distance is very small, then then then handler would do nothing

Comment: @DavidVotrubec, great! I'm working on an implementation. If there is more general methods, I would love to learn them.